# How to get relative file in Python from multiple folders depth?

Tags: python

I have a project where I'm trying to get a file from a relative path.

The folder structure is like this:

```
file 1 
Folder 1
     Folder 2
        file 2
```

How do I import file 2 inside file 1?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.